# Open html file on button click with python-plotly

Tags: python-2.7, plotly

Im writing a python script which reads from a file and plots graphs in seperate html files with plotly.I would like to have a button to redirect from one page to another(load from disc).I've come across this :

```
updatemenus = list([
dict(type="buttons",
buttons=list([dict(label = 'Next',method = 'update', args = ['shapes', []])])
)])

layout=go.Layout(title="Iteration_Number:"+str(counter_iter),updatemenus=updatemenus)
```

But this is used for updating data or changing layout. What i want is open another html page from disc on button click. Is that possible ?

I have also seen this :

```
import webbrowser
url = "file:///home/tinyOS/Simulation_"+str(counter_iter+1)+".html"

webbrowser.open(url)
```

Which helps me open a new page but again i want it to happen when clicking on the button.Any ideas? Thanks a lot !

Comment: If you are working with python and your own HTML files it might be better to just work with [flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) which is what plotly is built on. You can use [d3](https://d3js.org/) or [charts.js](https://www.chartjs.org/) for plotting charts. Check out [this site](https://pythonspot.com/flask-and-great-looking-charts-using-chart-js/) to see how it can be done. I know this doesn't answer your question but may prove to be a better route.

Answer (score 0):

From the question I understand that you want a group of buttons on the plotly graph, that are going to open a plotly graph in new tab.

So you need not use plotly buttons for this requirements.because they are mainly used for `restyle`, `relayout`, etc., so there is no relation between these buttons and opening links in new tabs.

I would recommend having simple html buttons which on click are going to take you to the new tab.

A simple way to do it will be,  wrap the plot in a `div` set to relative positioning and make the `div` wrapping the button absolute positioned and position it anywhere over the graph, please refer the below example and let me know if this solves your issue!

**Solution:**

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as py_offline
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
py_offline.init_notebook_mode()

display(HTML("""
<style>
.wrapper{
    position:relative;
}
.button-group{
    position:absolute;
    top:40px;
    left:90%;
    z-index: 30000;
}
.button-group a{
    display:block;
}
</style>
"""))
```

What is happening in the above piece of code is, first we include the necessary packages, then styles needed!

---

```
data = [go.Bar(
            x=['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
            y=[20, 14, 23]
    )]

display(HTML("""
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="button-group">
    <a href="http://google.com" target="_BLANK">Google It</a>
    <a href="http://yahoo.com" target="_BLANK">Yahoo It</a>
</div>"""
    +str(py_offline.plot(data, filename='plot_name' ,output_type="div", include_plotlyjs=False)) 
+ '</div>'))
```

The main piece of code, with which we embed the buttons is shown above, first we define the plotly plot , then using `display and html` functions, we can embed the buttons inside a `div` with class `button-group` and with CSS we position that button.

Please do try the above code and let me know if there are any doubts regarding the working!

Comment: @NLD does this answer help you?